# автоматическая высота у embed

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать автоматической высоту блоку

```
<div class="recInner" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    <embed src="blablabla.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="950" height="100%" quality="high" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" alt="bla bla bla" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Указать в `vh` (проценты от высоты вьюпорта):

```
style="... height: 100vh;"
```

```html
<div class="recInner" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;">
    <embed src="blablabla.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  quality="high" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" alt="bla bla bla" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, нужно, чтобы блок обертка подстраивался под высоту контента, а так он будет брать весь экран